# Mocha, go to the next file after timeout

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm running my test files with script

```
"test": "node_modules/.bin/mocha *.test.js
```

but in the first test I'm sending to my Node.js server `while(1);` and causing it to timeout, simultaneously failing that test. That's the intended behaviour but how do I make mocha run the rest of the files after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in Mocha's repository for your case.
[Infinite loops seem to escape timeouts #1609](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1609)

**TL:DR** 
This is not possible in mocha(because of how node works).

You can read the interesting discussion about this problem.
The reason it blocks all the code is because of how node works.
The code is executed line by line totally in syncronous way.

The async magic happens with the node event loop .
But when you run infinite  loop the event loop will be blocked because only one event can run at a time, and this event will never end:)

Comment: Yep.  Busy waits are death in Node